# AirPlay turns my secondary monitor into a mirroring device

Tags: display, airplay, mirroring

I just replaced a BenQ monitor by an LG Ultrawide one as a secondary device to my 2017 Macbook Pro. When using AirPlay to my Apple TV (AirPlaying the Macbook screen), I used to be able to keep using my secondary monitor as if nothing was happening.

However, since I changed my secondary screen, turning on AirPlay automatically turns on this secondary screen into mirroring mode (with a terrible stretch due to the aspect ratio differences).

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by clicking on `Use as Separate Display` and going back to `Mirroring Retina Display`. Sometimes the windows get a little messed up, but it's much better now!